# Where did the pronunciation of "knowledge" as "now-ledge" come from?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

My father, was an educated, scholarly American gentleman raised in Colorado.  He spoke, read and wrote in English and German, and could read and write in Greek, Latin and Hebrew.  He always pronounced the word knowledge as now-ledge.  He said he grew up pronouncing it that way.

Has anyone else ever heard this? Does anyone know where it comes from?

Comment: by "now", do you mean "ow" as in *cow,* or "ow" as in *crow*?

Comment: I do have a vague recollection of reading that 'know-ledge' was an  old-fashioned way to pronounce the word, but I can't remember where.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary says this about the pronunciation of *knowledge* with the "long o" sound of the corresponding verb *know*:

> The now standard pronunciation with short stem vowel has developed from a form with Middle English reduction of the diphthong *ou* to short *ŏ* (see E. J. Dobson *Eng. Pronunc.* 1500–1700 (ed. 2, 1968) II. §14). An alternative pronunciation reflecting the usual development of Middle English *ou* to long open *ō* is recorded by the 16th-cent. orthoepist John Hart, and persisted into the 20th cent. (no doubt influenced by the pronunciation of *know* v.); thus N.E.D. (1901) records an occasional pronunciation (nōu·lėdʒ) /ˈnəʊlɪdʒ/, as do various editions of Webster (from 1911 onwards; labelled as ‘sometimes, especially in British usage’), and D. Jones *Eng. Pronunc. Dict.* up to ed. 13 (1969; labelled as ‘rare’).

Comment: I've never heard "knowledge" pronounced "now-ledge"; it's always been "nah-ledge" to me, rhyming with "college".   Benjamin Jowett,  a 19th-century Master of Balliol College, Oxford, had this little rhyme written about him:

First come I. My name is Jowett. / There's no knowledge but I know it. / I am Master of this College, / What I don't know isn't knowledge.

Comment: @tautophile: yes, the "nolledge" pronunciation seems to be pretty old, since the OED says it developed from a Middle English form. The "now-ledge" pronunciation might be considered an analogical or spelling-based restoration, like the shift that supposedly occurred from pronouncing "forehead" as "forrid" to pronouncing it as "fore-hed".

Comment: I never pronounce "forehead" as "fore-head"; I always say "forred".

Comment: @herisson, the first syllable is "now" as in "cow".  My father pronounced this word this way his whole life and I thought it was just him.  Recently though, I heard a guest on NPR say "now-ledge".  My Dad was born in Colorado but learned German along with English from his parents who were from Ohio.  His family immigrated from Germany in the 1840's.  He was a Lutheran pastor with the equivalent of a Masters Degree in the Classics.